# Numpy array 'WRITEABLE' reset on copy... how do I stop it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I create a numpy array `n` and set it to read-only by setting the `WRITEABLE` flag to `False`. Suppose I then send a copy of `n` to `x`, i.e:

```
x = deepcopy(n)
```

I would expect `x` to have the same state as `n`, and I would expect `x.flags['WRITEABLE']` to be `False`. Alas, it is `True`. I can of course work around this, but is there something I can do differently so I don't have to?

Comment: Are you using `copy.deepcopy`? Try using the native `numpy.copy`.

Comment: @kindall That should make no difference I suspect. `flags['WRITEABLE']` just records the attributes about the underlying memory. When you make a new copy, then a new block of allocated memory is created, and this memory is writeable.

Comment: I would expect a NumPy-specific copy operation to know about that and make such attributes the same on the copy, and I'd consider it a bug if it doesn't. But that's why I suggested trying it.  :-)

Comment: Actually np.copy works as @kindall says... so thanks! Super annoying though... now Im going to have to go and write individual copy methods for my classes rather than being able to depend on the Pythonic solution. Grrr!

Comment: Nah, if you write a `__deepcopy__` special method on your classes, you should be able to leverage the `numpy` implementation, and then use `deepcopy` as usual.

Comment: Strange. I just checked np.copy seems to work like deepcopy. http://pastebin.com/uR5b6y0h Which version of NumPy?

Comment: You are absolutely right, @John Galt, it does not work... Internally NumPy calls [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_NewCopy) C API function, which returns an array that is "is always aligned and writeable". `copy` will preserve Fortran arrays, `deepcopy` not even that.

Comment: So actually @Jaime you are correct.  Neither deepcopy NOR np.copy preserve flag.  I have confirmed by experimentation. The reason I thought the np.copy method worked earlier in the day is that, when I tried it, I also changed something else (don't want to get into details), and I basically tricked myself.  :)  But, clearly, running this code, shows that you guys are right: 


`x = np.array([1, 1, 1])`
`x.setflags(write=False)`
`y = np.copy(x)`
`print(x.flags)`
`print(y.flags)` Sorry for knee jerk confirmation!  Should have been more careful.  Regardless, I made copy methods for each class.

Comment: @ali_m Thanks for the edits.  I had to type this question out using my phone, so I wasn't as good with the flags as I should have been!